# Array being saved to file not being properly populated once unserialized

Tags: php, file

I am trying to write code to receive an **item id(int)** and a **discount percentage(float)** then add them into an array which is meant to be stored into a file. However when I look at the array, it doesn't seem to e returned properly once read from the file.

I am using the following code:

```
    <?php
$myfile = fopen("discountsList.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$discounts = [];
$discounts = unserialize(fread($myfile, "r"));

$discounts ["".$_POST['item']]=[$_POST['percentage']];

//Test Data
/*$discounts = [
    "1" => 50.0,
    "5" => 15.5
];*/



file_put_contents("discountsList.txt", "");
fwrite($myfile, serialize($discounts));
fclose($myfile);
if (isset($_POST['leave'])) header("Location: index.html");
else header("Location: admin_dashboard.php?status=completed");
exit();
```

How can I make it so I could store the data properly into an array once it is read from the file and also store it into the file appropriately.

Also the way I am trying to do it is so that if the index already has been set that it replaces the value instead of making a new index.

Comment: Go back to the [PHP filesystem documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php). There's a lot of odd stuff in the code snippet above. `"a+"` feels like the wrong mode for `fopen`, the second argument to `fread` is a length and you have `"r"`, and `file_put_contents` and `fwrite` both kind of do the same thing. You should be able to do everything you want using just `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`, without using `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, or `fclose` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to to solve this removing all `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, and  `fclose` statements.

The working code should look something like this:

```
$discounts = [];
$discounts = unserialize(file_get_contents("discountsList.txt"));
$discounts ["" . $_POST['item']] = [$_POST['percentage']];
```

Using the `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` you are ale to read and write to the whole file; this is required in order to take care of the whole file at a time.

```
file_put_contents("discountsList.txt", "");
file_put_contents("discountsList.txt", serialize($discounts));
if (isset($_POST['leave'])) header("Location: index.html");
else header("Location: admin_dashboard.php?status=completed");
exit();
```